# javascript var assign a dynamic nullable value shows script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a JSON string returned from my asp.net mvc3 application controller using viewbag key as below, depending on various scenarios it can be null too

```
{"Name":"TShirt","Id":"85","Gender":"M","Size":"Medium"}
```

and I am trying to assign this JSON object to my local anonymous variable as shown below:

```
    var data = '@ViewBag.UserData';
```

The above ViewBag is null on initial page load, but as the user keys in the criteria, I store this into a session variable. Whenever user selects a product and clicks on `back to previous page`  link, I restore these filters froms session and place them in Viewbag for further processing on the View.

This is working perfectly fine when user clicks `back to previous page` , but I see a script error on the initial load because the `var data = '@ViewBag.UserData';` evaluates to `var data = ;`

I tried the below too but am still seeing the error

```
var data = '@ViewBag.UserData' != '' ? @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.UserData): {};
```

I tried

```
var data = '@ViewBag.UserData' != '' ? '@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.UserData)': {};
```

but I am unable to parse the `data` that I get in the  `back to previous page` scenario. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you do @ViewBag.UserData without quotes when using ternary?

Comment: it evaluates to something like this and still a script error `var data = '' != '' ? : {};`

Comment: you used @Html.Raw with quotes there? try both wihout?

Comment: the above comment output is for `var data = '@ViewBag.UserData' != '' ? @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.UserData): {};`

Comment: `var data = '@(ViewBag.UserData ?? Html.Raw(""))';`

Comment: You realize that leaving out the quotes gives you a javascript object instead of a string that has to be parsed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so clear that what you really wanted. But as per my understanding, I think you are looking for JSON parser.

```
var str = '{"one":"1","two":"2"}';
console.log(str); // Prints string
var obj = JSON.parse(str); //Converts string to JSON object
console.log(obj); // Prints JSON object
```

Comment: Rama Rao, exactly what I wanted. I tried $.parseJson but it didnt work, so I thought parsing isn't the right approach. I must have done a mistake while trying to parse

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace `''` to `null` or `{}` . May be the code works.

```
var data = '@ViewBag.UserData' != **null or {}** ? '@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.UserData)': {};
```